# Not able to resolve com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-photoview

I am using photoview from this library `com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.1`. But my Gradle is not getting synced.

[image: error]

[image: gradle file]

I have already added the Maven code from Gradle Dependancy on this url: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: See here [Gradle Dependency](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I have already done this still the error is coming

Comment: Have you added `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` ?

Comment: Make sure you added at your root gradle . classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'

Comment: @chris: names like Gradle and Maven are not code, and do not need formatting as such. An initial cap is fine.

Comment: @QuokMoon I added classpath still same error

Answer (score 14):

I had this issue and solved this by adding the repository in buildscript. Here you can see my build.gradle (not the module, but the project one) :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I don't know why I needed to do that because one my friend just added the repository in the allprojects block and it works for him.

Answer (score 3):

Add in your gradle.settings:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of this library is `2.0.0` [ as of `18 Mar 2017`] (not `1.3.1`) See [releases](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/releases).

Use this in your module level `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
```

Tested ok (here's where `gradle/jitpack` found it):

```
Download https://jitpack.io/com/github/chrisbanes/PhotoView/2.0.0/PhotoView-2.0.0.pom
Download https://jitpack.io/com/github/chrisbanes/PhotoView/2.0.0/PhotoView-2.0.0.aar
```

Answer (score 2):

Paste this:

```
maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
```

in *settings.gradle*, and paste this dependency:

```
implementation'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:latest.release.here'
```

in *build.gradle*.

[settings.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McE74.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add "library" after photoview
ex: implementation "com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.4"

https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library#statistics

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, solved after some attempts !

In your build.gradle file you should have the two last lines.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        // for photo view
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

Then add the lastest version.

```
// photo view
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
```

This should work hope it will helps.

Answer (score -1):

Add to settings.gradle:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }
```